# Как в функцию передать json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, json

не могу понять, почему внутри функции `json` = `undefined`. Почему так происходит? Первый `console.log()` нормально выводит `json`.

```
var r = {...}

console.log(r);

(function (r) {
   console.log(r);
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что аргументы и переменные надо именовать понятно для себя и других.

```
(function (r) {
   console.log(r);
})();
```

Что здесь `r`? Просто имя аргумента. Оно никак не связано с переменной `r` объявленной ранее. А так как называется аргумент так же как и переменная, то в теле функции вам недоступна переменная `r`. Запутанно? Вот поэтому надо именовать переменные правильно:

```
(function (jsonStr) {
   console.log(r);       // выводим глобальную переменную r
   console.log(jsonStr); // выводим аргумент, он не передан, поэтому undefined
})();

(function (jsonStr) {
   console.log(r);       // выводим глобальную переменную r
   console.log(jsonStr); // выводим аргумент, он передан и равен глобальной переменной r
})(r);
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому, что вы не передаете в функцию параметр.

А входной параметр `r` скрывает глобальную переменную `r`

Вот рабочий пример

```js
var r = {a: 1};

console.log(r);

(function (r) {
   console.log(r);
})(r);
```

Фактически происходит такой вызов

```js
var r = {a: 1};

console.log(r);

(function (a) {
   console.log(a);
})(r);
```

Также будет работать, если входной параметр убрать совсем

```js
var r = {a: 1};

console.log(r);

(function () {
   console.log(r);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

В сигнатуре анонимной функции есть параметр. А в вызове - параметра нет.

```
(function (r) {
   console.log(r);
})(r);
```